# Как рассчитать информацию из файла csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

У меня есть файл out_92.csv, и я хочу подсчитать, каких чисел больше во втором столбце «receiving phone» и сколько из этих номеров.

```
calling phone;receiving phone;date;price
92;31;2020-04-24;0
92;84;2021-01-19;19
92;31;2020-03-28;9
92;36;2021-01-15;11
92;31;2020-12-13;3
92;35;2020-09-07;16
92;97;2020-07-01;9
92;31;2020-05-20;16
92;31;2020-09-03;13
92;56;2020-06-26;5
92;31;2020-02-25;10
92;17;2020-10-05;7
92;93;2020-07-14;7
92;84;2020-05-13;13
92;31;2020-05-27;12
92;45;2021-01-07;8
92;31;2020-07-18;16
92;74;2021-01-16;1
92;68;2020-08-22;13
92;31;2020-11-03;12
92;75;2020-02-19;16
92;82;2020-10-02;13
92;41;2020-03-06;17
92;43;2020-10-09;13
92;31;2020-12-14;17
92;47;2020-04-02;3
92;31;2021-01-06;1
```

Comment: Прочитать данные из файла в Датафрейм (например), а потом применить работать с методами Pandas. Скрпит получается  -  по одной строчке на каждое написанное вами действие. Правда, фраза "и сколько из этих номеров." выглядит как неоконченная мысль -  но уж как получается.

Answer (score 2):

Пример работы с `Pandas` (вообще лучше читать данные из файла, но у меня файла нет, я подменяю файл строкой):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(\
'''calling phone;receiving phone;date;price
92;31;2020-04-24;0
92;84;2021-01-19;19
92;31;2020-03-28;9
92;36;2021-01-15;11
92;31;2020-12-13;3
92;35;2020-09-07;16
92;97;2020-07-01;9
92;31;2020-05-20;16
92;31;2020-09-03;13
92;56;2020-06-26;5
92;31;2020-02-25;10
92;17;2020-10-05;7
92;93;2020-07-14;7
92;84;2020-05-13;13
92;31;2020-05-27;12
92;45;2021-01-07;8
92;31;2020-07-18;16
92;74;2021-01-16;1
92;68;2020-08-22;13
92;31;2020-11-03;12
92;75;2020-02-19;16
92;82;2020-10-02;13
92;41;2020-03-06;17
92;43;2020-10-09;13
92;31;2020-12-14;17
92;47;2020-04-02;3
92;31;2021-01-06;1''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';')
print(df['receiving phone'].value_counts())
```

Вывод:

```
31    11
84     2
93     1
56     1
68     1
82     1
17     1
47     1
45     1
75     1
74     1
41     1
43     1
36     1
35     1
97     1
Name: receiving phone, dtype: int64
```

Чаще всего встречается телефон 31 - аж 11 раз.